# Yii2 inserting new record on update

Tags: php, yii2

I have a setup where for one of the Model I have repeat fields like `user` and `userchildren`

so `userchildren` have a set of fields like `child_name`, `child_birth_date` and `child_gender`

My controller code is like this:

```
 public function actionUpdateProfile()
    {
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model = User::find()->where(['id' => $user_id])->one();

        $UserProfile = UserProfile::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->one();
        $userbillinginfo = UserBillingInfo::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->one();
        $userchildren = UserChildren::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->all();

        if ($userchildren) {
            $profile = $UserProfile;
            $billinginfo = $userbillinginfo;
            $userchild = $userchildren;
        } else {
            $profile = new UserProfile;
            $profile->user_id = $model->id;
            $billinginfo = new UserBillingInfo;
            $billinginfo->user_id = $model->id;
            $userchild = New UserChildren;
            $userchild->user_id = $model->id;

        }
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $profile->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($profile);
        }

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $billinginfo->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($billinginfo);
        }

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $userchild->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($userchild);
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $billinginfo->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $model->username = $model->email;
            $model->save();
            $profile->save();
            $billinginfo->save();
            if (!empty($_POST['UserChildren']) && !is_null($_POST['UserChildren'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['UserChildren'] as $rows) {
                    $userchild = New UserChildren;
                    $userchild->attributes = $rows;
                    $userchild->user_id = $model->id;
                    $userchild->save();
                }
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update-profile', [
                'model' => $model,
                'profile' => $profile,
                'billinginfo' => $billinginfo,
                'userchild' => $userchild,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I am facing two issues:
first, when I go for an update of the profile the data is shown properly in the form, I can add records without any issue to the Model `UserChildren`

1. But if I edit an existing record it is inserting this as a new record, whereas I expect this to be updated.
2. I had this line of code like below:

   ,

   ```
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) and
           $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) and
           $billinginfo->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) and
           $billinginfo->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
       ) {
   ...
   ```

but after I updated the line of code,

```
 $userchildren = UserChildren::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->one();
```

to

```
 $userchildren = UserChildren::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->all();
```

and thus had to modify the line like below:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $billinginfo->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
```

What I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: why you change  query->one() to ->all() ?

Comment: for UserChildren Model there are repeat fields that is `Userchildren` have multiple record related to `User Model`. when I open the form for update the existing data for User children are not getting pulled if I keep that -`>one`

Comment: how are you populating the `UserChildren` in the form add your form code.